# Create a socket that the mobile client can listen on to get notifications

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a client mobile app that needs to listen for updates from the server. But the server send the message oly to one client at once (it is not a broadcasting). How can I kep track of whom to send the message to, and send it using sockets?
should the mobile app be the server for the socket, or the asp.net server?

Comment: Does your client app's host have a reachable addr:port combination? I afraid most often they do not and may be behind NAT, restrictive firewall or some such. The usual solution is to listen on the server, connect from client, keep the connection active (a list of active connections on the server), then loop over the list if something happens. This is fast, not very scalable and has nothing to do with ASP. If this does not fit your requirements, please clarify and/or elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile app should be a client. It should have unique ID (a GUID works well). The server accepts a connection from the mobile app. The mobile app then sends its unique ID, the server creates a object that stores the socket and unique ID. If 10 clients connect, you store 10 sockets each with there own unqiue ID.

Now the server has an update to push out:

Loop through your objects, sending data down each socket to the mobile apps.

p.s I do not think asp.net would work for this. But you could easily code a C# .NET app.

EDIT:

Additionally, if you were to self-host an WCF service in the C# .NET app, then you could consume the service from the ASP.NET web application. Then, this would allow you to send data from the web application to the C# app and the C# app could pass that data down to the sockets, or trigger the c# app to send certain data down the sockets to the mobile apps.